# Weak supervision vs semi-supervised learning

Tags: machine-learning, semi-supervised-learning

What exactly is the difference between these two and when should they be used?

Context : I have a large set of unlabelled data. I can get a number of weak labels / labeling functions for all of the data, which seems ideal for weak supervision. But I can also get golden labels for a small set of data, and maybe try learning on that so wondering which approach is better.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi there! I notice that you are asking three questions. It may be a good idea to concentrate on a single issue and provide a bit more context in order to help members of the forum provide a good answer.

Comment: @ngiann Updated, thanks!

Comment: There are too many variables to be able to answer this question for you. It's not as if there's an 'exchange rate' between weakly labeled examples and gold examples. (I work on both.) The best answer is to try one or the other (or both) and see what you get. (But often, the 'cost' of labeling is greatly exaggerated—and it's worth the effort.)